# How can i access an Android drawable by a variable

Tags: android

How can i access an Adroid drawable by a variable?
Example
I have  drawables :[ logo1.png logo2.png ... logoN.png];
Is there a way so i can do that?

```
String logopicker="1";
logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.**logo+logopicker**);
```

Well i know this code will never run but you get the idea of what i want to do. 
Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code is running for me successful (I have already used in my one of the application),
You can Try this:

```
     cnt=1;

     String icon="logo" + cnt;
     int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable",  getPackageName()); 
     logo.setImageResource(resID); 

     cnt++;  // this require if you want to set images in loop
```

Enjoy !!

Comment: 1 sec before you replyed i found the answer from the api.
Nevertheless thank you very much.

Comment: sorry thought that marked as correct is enough (i'm new here :D)

Comment: getResources and getPackageName requires context

Comment: use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code