# Applying a background image to listview with textview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a listview with a static background image (i.e. not contained within the individual list cells, but fills the display and does not move when list is scrolled).  I've found a couple references here and am trying to implement, but no joy.  The first is;

[Set a background for a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989268/set-a-background-for-a-listview)

In particular, I'm trying this;

```
    //set background to Drawable
listView.setBackgroundDrawable(myDrawable);
```

To create the "myDrawable" variable, I'm using a suggestion from;

[How can I access an android drawable by a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218520/how-can-i-access-an-android-drawable-by-a-variable)

Again, the particular code I'm trying is;

```
String icon="logo" + cnt;
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable",  getPackageName()); 
 logo.setImageResource(resID);
```

Here is the code I created;

```
ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  String bg="football_turf_subtle";
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(bg, "drawable", getPackageName());
  myDrawable.setImageResource(resID);

  lv.setBackgroundDrawable(myDrawable);
```

The problem I'm running into in my code is "myDrawable cannot be resolved"?  If it's not obvious, I'm new to Android/Java.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.football_turf_subtle).

Comment: I thought I tried that and it didn't work.  But after you mentioned it, I tried it again and it works!  Thanks.  Now just need to eliminate the annoying turns black when you drag the list...   I appreciate your help!