# 400 ImageViews and a For, in Android

Tags: android

I'm making an layout with 400 imageView. The question is how I can set R.id.imageView>>**i**<<

```
for(int i = 1; i < 401; i++){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView-i-);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i access an Android drawable by a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218520/how-can-i-access-an-android-drawable-by-a-variable)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 400; i++) {
    String s = "imageview" + i;
    int id = getResources.getIdentifier(s, "id", getPackageName ());
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById (id);
}
```

This should work